# Could a passing comet's gravitational pull rotate a close-by smaller tidally locked planet 20 degrees?

Tags: planets, science-fiction

In my story, I need a tidally locked planet to rotate about 20 degrees. I would like to write that the gravitational pull of a large Comet passing by (not hitting) the planet is strong enough to rotate that planet about 20 degrees. Let's say the tidally locked planet is the size of our moon.

Comment: [Betteridge's Law of Headlines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betteridge's_law_of_headlines) applies.

Comment: Hello Paul, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Please take our [tour] and read the following two Help Center pages ([help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]) to better understand how to ask questions. To expand a bit on @AlexP's comment, it would take a monstrously large comment to do what you're asking and it would change the orbit along with the rotation. But that's in the Real World. We're in the business of helping people create imaginary worlds. In your world, said comet has an unusually heavy pull. Cool! What else can we help you with?

Comment: @JBH "Monstrously large comment". Hehe.

Comment: @Joachim Oh, crap. Whadaya think... Freudian slip? Not that I'm bragging or anything.

Comment: JBH, thanks for your welcome and your suggestion that my comet has an usually heavy pull. I'm gonna stay away from your "monstrously large comment" comment. Too many ways it could go wrong!

Answer (score 1):

It's highly unlikely.

To rotate a body you need to apply a torque to it.

To apply a torque to it via gravitational means, the body would need to be "slightly unbalanced", e.g. the configuration of the test masses in [Cavendish experiment](https://www.school-for-champions.com/science/gravitation_cavendish_experiment.htm#.Y5q_UPzMKUk) with a torsion pendulum.

[image]

Since you talk about a planet, it is by definition in hydrostatic equilibrium, so it is a spheroid. It might have local inhomogeneities, but not as evident as the two spheres with a stick.

And for the comet to be able to exert an appreciable force on it in the short time it will transit in its neighborhood, it should be way more massive than the planet itself, but at that point it could just capture the planet as its own satellite.